# Kayue\WordpressBundle with Symfony 4.4.1: The class XXX was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, entitymanager

I'm trying to work with [kayue/KayueWordpressBundle](https://github.com/kayue/KayueWordpressBundle) installed with composer as `composer require kayue/kayue-wordpress-bundle` in my Symfony 4.4.1 project but I'm unable to.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service\WordPress;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\Post;

class PostCollection
{
    protected $postRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->postRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(Post::class);
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
The class 'Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\Post' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity
```

[At first I blamed my dual-database configuration](https://github.com/kayue/KayueWordpressBundle/issues/89) (Symfony is on a different DB from Wordpress) but then I put the DBs together and the issue persists:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # Only needed for MySQL (ignored otherwise)
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

I've been fiddling for the past 2hrs, but now I'm fresh out of ideas. I wonder if ANYONE actually got this to work with Symfony 4.

Thanks!

Edit: other tries:

**Direct post injection:**

```
use Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\Post;
public function index(Post $post){}
```

Result:

*Cannot autowire argument $post of "App\Controller\IndexController::index()": it references class "Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\Post" but no such service exists.*

**As per documentation: outdated Symfony 2 way**

```
$repo = $this->get('kayue_wordpress')->getManager()->getRepository('KayueWordpressBundle:Post');
```

Result:

*Service "kayue_wordpress" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\IndexController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.*

**The "best way" to do this would actually be:**

```
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
$entityManager->getRepository('KayueWordpressBundle:Post');
}
```

Result:

*The class 'Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\Post' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity*

Comment: Did you use composer to install the bundle?  That should have taken care of the autoloading.  You could try "composer dump-autoload" though that should have been run automatically.

Comment: Yes, I installed as installed with composer as `composer require kayue/kayue-wordpress-bundle` (question updated with this step, thanks). Flex executed (I see it in bundles.php).

Comment: Did you make yourself a config/packages/kayue_wordpress.yaml file?  Because Flex is not going to do that for you without a recipe.  Probably not the problem though.

Comment: Yes, I created the config/packages/kayue_wordpress.yaml file myself. It just contains the connection name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you found a solution to this, there is a chain of issues I would like to explain.

The error

> The class 'Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\Post' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

means that ***in the entity manager provided***, whose config is defined at:

```
orm:
    ...
    mappings:
        App:
        ...
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

the entity type **Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity\Post** was not found.

Usually this type of error is solved by:

- include the path **Kayue\WordpressBundle\Entity** in the entity manager or
- use another entity manager which includes this path

In your case the **default entity manager is autowired**, based on the service alias of **Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface** as explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-logic-explained). The alias is defined in the [doctrine bundle `s config](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/2.0.x/Resources/config/orm.xml#L78) which points to the default doctrine entity manager.

You want to **use Kayue\WordpressBundle `s entity manager, not the default one**.

### Solution

To solve this you can

1) [Bind Arguments By type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type), as you find out, creating an alias of **Kayue\WordpressBundle\Wordpress\ManagerRegistry** to the service **kayue_wordpress**, as:

```
services:
      # pass this service for any ManagerRegistry type-hint for any
      # service that's defined in this file
      Kayue\WordpressBundle\Wordpress\ManagerRegistry: '@kayue_wordpress'
```

***or***

2) use [**Binding Arguments by Name**](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type), in this case the "**$wpManagerRegistry**", as:

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        ...
        bind:
            $wpManagerRegistry: '@kayue_wordpress'
```

and then

```
public function index($wpManagerRegistry)
{

    $postRepository = $wpManagerRegistry->getManager()->getRepository('KayueWordpressBundle:Post');
```

so that any argument with name "$wpManagerRegistry" is **autowired** to this service.

### References

[The Symfony 3.3 DI Container Changes Explained (autowiring, _defaults, etc)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

My collegue found a solution. You must configure the autowire like this:

```
// config/packages/kayue_wordpress.yaml

services:
  Kayue\WordpressBundle\Wordpress\ManagerRegistry: '@kayue_wordpress'
```

After that, you can autowire:

```
use Kayue\WordpressBundle\Wordpress\ManagerRegistry;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $wpManagerRegistry)
    {
        $this->wpPostRepository = $wpManagerRegistry->getManager()->getRepository('KayueWordpressBundle:Post');
    }

public function getPosts()
{
$post = $this->wpPostRepository->findOneBy(array(
        'slug'   => 'hello-world',
        'type'   => 'post',
        'status' => 'publish',
    ));
}
```